# Laravel HasManyThrough not returning any results

Tags: laravel, has-many-through

I have the following tables (each is modeled) with a relation that I need to draw, I picked  (only relevant columns for brevity):

`requests.id` relates through `user_deposits.request_id`

and then,

`user_deposits.id` relates through `user_deposits_files.f_id`

so I wrote:

```
public function financialRequestDeposit(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        'App\UserDepositFile',
        'App\UserDeposit',
        'request_id',
        'f_id',
        'id',
        'id'
    );
}
```

Even though the above code looks like a ship's keel, I am getting an empty array of items, any susceptible reason why?

Thanks!

> EDIT from here>>>>

#### **controller**

`dd($deposit = FinancialRequest::where('id', $id)->with([ 'financialRequestDeposit'])->first());`

Comment: Please post the code of Models and also the Controller in which you are accessing the Model.

Comment: @AmandeepSingh edited

Comment: Is `$deposit` empty/null? Or `$deposit->financialRequestDeposit`?